# C Error - What does the number stand for?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, line-numbers

I couldn't find anything on this, but probably its just because I don't know how to search, because i don't know how to call it.

I tried to compile some C-Code and got the following error:

```
/path/to/file.h:55:32: error: path/to/include.h: No such file or directory
```

I know the error and i know that the problem is in `file.h` at `line 55` - where's an include, which doesn't exist.

But what does the `32` stand for?

Marty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the number of the character within line `55`.

This might also be referred to as "column number" (see comment) but I find that slightly misleading, as e.g. a tab character will generally take up more than one column in your editor, but still count as only one character for the compiler.

Comment: That's what I also thought, but the line is: `#include "arch/i960/regsI960.h"` - why 32?

Comment: It's the end of the line, which is the point where the entire include is known and can be processed.

Comment: Holy Sh** - its the new line character. Doesn't make sense to me... but thanks anyway :)